# Can any one tell about what kind of issue I am seeing in my Macbook pro 10.12.1, i am seeing verticle lines in one part of screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

When i tried to take screenshot of issue, it is not getting captured.Screen is turning black and then white

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware fault in the screen. Your MacBook Pro needs its screen replacing.